# We are very unlucky in my court

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Just made this up for the riddle whiteboard at work; but I reckon you guys will crack it immediately.

> We are very unlucky in my court,
>   But with rival groups, we play sport.
>   There are 3 other groups, just like us,
>   Who we all are, out you must suss.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are

> A suit of cards.

We are very unlucky in my court

> There are 13 cards in a suit of cards, and 13 is considered an unlucky by many people.  "Court" could also be a reference to the court cards - J, Q and K.

But with rival groups, we play sport

> When combined with the other suits to make a full deck, many games can be played.

There are 3 other groups, just like us

> The other 3 suits + this one make the four suits of a deck.

Comment: I was thinking "who we all are" as the complete deck of cards but you got everything else right so get the green tick :)

Answer (score 9):

We are very unlucky in my court,

> ?

But with rival groups, we play sport.

> sports clubs

There are 3 other groups, just like us,

> spades, hearts, diamonds

Who we all are, out you must suss.

> You are **clubs**.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but only one line is half-correct.

Answer (score 5):

You describe

> a game of four player ludo

---

We are very unlucky in my court,

> because after beating a pawn (maybe wrongly translated, I mean the figurines) it gets reset to point zero and has to start over.

But with rival groups, we play sport.

> The groups of pawns race to get into the "home". Without rivals, it wouldn't be sport

There are 3 other groups, just like us,

> there are 4 groups of pawns similar to the first group. One group for each player.

Who we all are, out you must suss.

> you are the pawns of a player of the game.